# How to converting an array to a dictionary in Javascript (also re-order columns into rows)?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, javascript-objects

I have the following array of arrays:

```js
[
  [o1, c1, h1, l1 ,t1],
  [o2, c2, h2, l2, t2],
  ...
  [oN, cN, hN, lN, tN]
]
```

I need to convert this into an object that is structured in the following way:

```js
{
  open:   [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6,o7,o8, ... oN],
  close:  [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8, ... cN],
  high:   [h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8, ... hN],
  low:    [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8, ... lN],
  time:   [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8, ... tN]
}
```

So this means that an additional problem that I need to solve is reorganising the columns into rows.

The following is the code that works for me:

```js
function convertData(rawDataArray) {
  [open, close, high, low, timesignature] = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ];
  var arrayLength = rawDataArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    open.push(rawDataArray[i][1])
    close.push(rawDataArray[i][2])
    high.push(rawDataArray[i][3])
    low.push(rawDataArray[i][4])
    timesignature.push(rawDataArray[i][0])
  }
  return {
   open: open,
    close: close,
    high: high,
    low: low,
    timeSignature: timesignature
  }
}
```

However, my solution seems to me as a clunky and not very elegant one. I am curious to learn a way to write this in a more efficient way.

Comment: if you are looking for perfomances, your code is maybe the best solution to that problem, because accessing array by positions has complexity O(1). If you are looking for compactness and/or readability, you could use some `map` or `reduce` instead

Comment: I have the impression that methods such as `.map` are designed to be performance optimizations as well. Is that not the case? By the way, I accepted the `.map` based answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by elegant you mean easier-to-read code and not necessarily faster performance-wise. This is where `map()` comes in handy because it reduces the clunky for loop into one single line.

```
function convertData(rawDataArray) {
    return {
        open: rawDataArray.map(i=>i[0]),
        close: rawDataArray.map(i=>i[1]),
        high: rawDataArray.map(i=>i[2]),
        low: rawDataArray.map(i=>i[3]),
        timeSignature: rawDataArray.map(i=>i[4])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let row =[
  ["o1", "c1", "h1", "l1","t1"],
  ["o2", "c2", "h2", "l2", "t2"]
]
const extractIndex = (ind,data)=> data.map(e=>e[ind]) 
const convertDataNew = (rawDataArray)=> {
  return {
    open: extractIndex(0,rawDataArray),
    close: extractIndex(1,rawDataArray),
    high: extractIndex(2,rawDataArray),
    low: extractIndex(3,rawDataArray),
    timeSignature: extractIndex(4,rawDataArray)
  }

}


console.log(convertDataNew(row))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have two answers. Very difficult decision. I think I will go with @fjch1997's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the keys and use them as part of the property accesssor for pushing the value.

```
function convertData(rawDataArray) {
    var keys = ['open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'time'],
        result = Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: [] })));

    rawDataArray.forEach(a => keys.forEach((k, i) => result[k].push(a[i])));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting solution as well.

Comment: I don't get it. `k` isn't defined in the lambda expression `a => k.forEach(...)`

Comment: sorry. it should be `keys`.